# Limit Find the value of C given function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Limit Find the value of $c$ given function

Find $c$, such that the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 & {1 - \sqrt{x} \over x - 1},&0\le x < 1\\ 
 & c,& x= 1
\end{cases}$$

is continuous for all $x \in [0, 1 ]$.

I try to solve that question on interval $x = 0$ i get answer $-1$, with $f(0)$, and get undefined on limit so this is discontinous.

but when the $x$ is $1$ how can i solve? and How i get value of $c$?

i try the following approach

on left hand limit we get $- 1 / 2 $ but on right hand limit we have nothing!. to me this function seems to  not complete. this was the assignment i told our teacher to upload solution of this, but he didnt do that till yet.

Sorry, if it is nonsense question; i am software engineer student and on 2nd sem we're studying calculus subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Rewriting this answer)*

That's fine. The requirement for continuity
$$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x) = f(x_0)$$
implicitly means that as $x\to x_0$, it does so through values of $x\neq x_0$ that are in the domain of $f$.

So if $x_0 = 1$, all of the domain values of $f$ are the to left of $x_0$. You are therefore implicitly computing a one-sided limit, and $x\nearrow 1$.

The limit depends only on values of $f(x)$ for $x<1$. If this happens to equal the value of $f(x)$ for $x=1$, then $f$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As $x \to 1^-$, $\frac{1 - \sqrt x}{x-1} \to -\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, for $x$ to be continuous at $x=1$, $c = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: where the right hand ? pls explain more.

Comment: So we have $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(c)$. Check through the three conditions for $x$ to be continuous [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) if you're not convinced.

Comment: \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c) 
for limit at c we need both left and right limit, but in that case we have just left limit, so without right hand limit how is it continous?

Comment: It is still continuous at $x = 1$, but it is just right continuous. What I have done is use the one-sided limit to show continuity. The normal definition of continuity works for all $x \in (a, b)$, but you have to use this definition for $x = a$ or $x = b$.

Comment: Thanks, sorry i didnt knew that because we didnt study that topic yet in second semester of software engineering in calculus